# Cannot find mean with my given data in r-software

Tags: r

So I have been given this data and I cannot find mean & median.

```
Roll No. 1 2 3 4 5 6
Marks 28 48 48 37 31 37
Roll No. 7 8 9 10 11 12
Marks 35 57 40 51 32 60
Roll No. 13 14 15 16 17 18
Marks 61 67 47 62 35 50
Roll No. 19 20 21 22 23 24
Marks 29 69 42 63 40 54
Roll No. 25 26 27 28 29 30
Marks 36 50 41 33 38 56
```

Data <- read.table("mydirectory/goes/here", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
The output of data is some gibberish thingy which I'm sure is not something I wanted.

```
$Roll
[1] "Marks"

$No.
[1] "61"

$X1
[1] 48

$X2
[1] 40

$X3
[1] 33

$X4
[1] 31

$X5
[1] 37

$X6
[1] 21
```

The above is the output. I think something is wrong with t provided table/data but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think the main trouble is reading the data. Your data seems to be inverted with no clear separator in it.

Comment: type class(yourdataname) , if it's dataframe, then the problem is with your delimiter. You can choose a more automated package if you can't figure it out

Comment: @RonakShah I thought that too. How do I change the data format to a proper one? I tried writing Roll and Marks individually in notepad, but it is getting Marks section as "NA".

Comment: If you can edit the data in notepad remove the spaces between `Roll No.` to make it `RollNo.` and then use `Data <- read.table('/path/of/file')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Omar113 mentioned in the comment, the problem was with the delimiter and my dataset was meant to be saved as in CSV. I manually made the CSV with proper formatting as Ronak told me, and I fixed it.
Thanks!